# nextval function in oracle query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have two oracle queried.In the first query when i insert, i insert Sequesnce Next value (nextval) then i need to insert it to the next query.Intermediately i need to return the Current value ( currval).

> Error is :
> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

I think this happen in currval function ?
Query

```
 string query = @"INSERT INTO TBL_TICKET_TYPE(NewsID,NAME) 
                                 VALUES(newsid.nextval,:NAME)";

            cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query);

            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "NAME", DbType.String, TicketTypes.NAME);

            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);

            //String query3 = "Select newsid.currval from dual";


            String query2 = "INSERT INTO TBL_TICKET_TYPE_TAX(TICKETTYPEID,TAXID)VALUES(newsid.currval,:LINENO)";
            cxd = db.GetSqlStringCommand(query);
            db.AddInParameter(cxd, "LINENO", DbType.Int32, 1);
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cxd);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is start with a query to fetch `newsid.nextval` and put the result into a variable:

```
SELECT newsid.nextval FROM dual;
```

Then you can use this variable in `query` (in place of `newsid.nextval`) and `query2` (in place of newsid.currval).

Hope this helps.

Comment: There is an issue with such a way, since each run will increase the index by 1